# What should i do to recover the deleted heroku app database?

Tags: database, heroku

My application was unsubscribed from the platform but they tell me that I can still get a copy of the database and I did what they told me was to register again with the previous email address and verify my account with a credit card but not lets me create the ticket to continue the process, asks me to select an application to continue but there are no applications in my account and I need a copy of my database

Comment: Have you deleted the account as well?

Comment: The solution was to contact heroku support using a ticket and they helped me recovering my database

Comment: Wasn't aware it works if account has been deleted , tried on app deletion though

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Juan : The solution was to contact heroku support using a ticket and they helped recovering the database

Comment: Hi!, was this on a hobby or production tier DB?

Comment: Not sure if they help with `Hobby Dev` but It was a paid plan in my case (Hobby Basic )